# Creating the first Celery task - Django. Error - "ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//:"

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

I'm trying to create my first Celery task. The task will send the same e-mail every one minute to the same person.

According to the documentation, I create my first task in my project.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from celery import shared_task
from django.core.mail import send_mail


@shared_task
def send_message():
    to = ['test@test.com', ]
    send_mail('TEST TOPIC',
              'TEST MESSAGE',
              'test@test.com',
              to)
```

Then, in my project's ja folder, I add the celery.py file, which looks like this:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings
from celery.schedules import crontab

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'app_rama.settings')

app = Celery('app_rama')

# Using a string here means the worker doesn't have to serialize
# the configuration object to child processes.
# - namespace='CELERY' means all celery-related configuration keys
#   should have a `CELERY_` prefix.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')

# Load task modules from all registered Django app configs.
app.autodiscover_tasks(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)


app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    'send-message-every-single-minute': {
        'task': 'app.tasks.send_message',
        'schedule': crontab(),  # change to `crontab(minute=0, hour=0)` if you want it to run daily at midnight
    },
}
```

Then in the `__int__.py` file of my project I added:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

# This will make sure the app is always imported when
# Django starts so that shared_task will use this app.
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ('celery_app',)
```

And the last thing I try to do is run the command:

```
celery -A app_rama worker -l info
```

And then I receive the following error:

```
[2019-06-27 16:01:26,750: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//: [WinError 10061]
```

I tried many solutions from the forum, but I did not find the correct one. 
I was also not helped by adding the following settings to my settings.py file:

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672//'
```

How can I solve this error so that my task works in the background of the application?

Answer (score 1):

Your Celery broker is probably misconfigured. Read the "[Using RabbitMQ](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/brokers/rabbitmq.html)" document to find out how to setup RabbitMQ properly (I assumed you want to use RabbitMQ as you had "amqp" protocol in your example).

I recommend learning Celery with Redis, as it is easier to setup and manage. Then once you learn the basics you may decide to move to RabbitMQ or some other supported broker...

Also, verify that your RabbitMQ server is running properly. If you use Windows, make sure some software on it does not prevent user processes to connect to the localhost:5672.